# Pyspark: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark (SQL Data Pool)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to load streaming data from Kafka into SQL Server Big Data Clusters Data Pools. I'm using Spark 2.4.5 (Bitnami 2.4.5 spark image).

If I want to load data into regular tables, I use this sentence and it goes well:

```
logs_df.write.format('jdbc').mode('append').option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver').option \
        ('url', 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX:31433;databaseName=sales;').option('user', user).option \
        ('password', password).option('dbtable', 'SYSLOG_TEST_TABLE').save()
```

But the same sentence to load data into SQL Data Pool gives me this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): java.sql.BatchUpdateException: External Data Pool Table DML statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.
```

I found that the way to load data into SQL Data Pool is to use 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark' format, as this:

```
logs_df.write.format('com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark').mode('append').option('url', url).option('dbtable', datapool_table).option('user', user).option('password', password).option('dataPoolDataSource',datasource_name).save()
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I'm running the script with spark-submit like this:

```
docker exec spark245_spark_1 /opt/bitnami/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar --jars /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5 /storage/scripts/some_script.py
```

Is there any other package I should include or some special import I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

*Edited: I've tried in scala with same results*

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the repository into the jar file first using SBT. Then include it to your spark cluster.

I know there will be a lot of people having trouble with buiding this jar file (include myself of several hours ago), so I will guide you how to build the jar file, step by step:

1. Go to https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html to download SBT, then install it.
2. Go to https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector and download the zip file.
3. Open the folder of the repository you have just downloaded, right click in the blank space and click "Open PowerShell windows here" .
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq7NX.png
4. In the Shell windows, type "sbt" then press enter. It may require you to download the Java Development Kit. If so, go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html to download and install it. You may need to close and reopen the shell windows after installing.

If things go right, you may see this screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMxVr.png

5. After the above step has done its job, type "package".
   The shell may show you something like this, and it may take you a long time to finish the job.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr2hw.png
6. After the build is done, go to the "target" folder, then "scala-2.11" folder to get the jar file.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aziqy.png
7. After you got the jar file, include it to the Spark cluster.

<strike>OR, if you don't want to do the troublesome procedures above....</strike>

UPDATE MAY 26, 2021: The connector is now available in Maven, so you can just go there and do the rest.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/spark-mssql-connector

If you need more information, just comment. I will try my best to help.

Comment: I found version 1.2 in Maven list, installed fine in Databricks, and solved problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: "To include the connector in your projects, download this repository and build the jar using SBT."

So you need to build the connector JAR file using the `build.sbt` in the repository, then put the JAR file into spark: `your_path\spark\jars`

To do this, download the SBT here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html. Open SBT in the directory where you saved the `build.sbt` then run `sbt package`. A `target` folder should be created in the same directory and the JAR file is located in `target\scala-2.11`