# Spark Driver Error -Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, databricks

What I have Done

I have Installed com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 To databricks cluster for spark 3.1.
Then trying to connect using JDBC but getting following error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

```
Host_Name='hoest name'
Database_name='Db_name'
jdbcPort=1433
jdbcUrl='"jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}"'.format(Host_Name,jdbcPort,Database_name)
UserName='username'
Password='password'
table='table'

jdbcDF = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
        .option("dbtable", table) \
        .option("user", UserName) \
        .option("password", Password).load()
```

I was expecting to read a table from SQL server as a spark data frame in data bricks

Comment: Does this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64022072/390122) help?